# How to enable Saltstack ssl connection between master and minion

Tags: ssl, salt-stack

I try to enable ssl for Saltstack master and minion by following https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#ssl But I am not sure how to verify it is using SSL.

I added this in master configuration:

```
ssl:
  keyfile: /etc/salt/ssl/master/key.pem
  certfile: /etc/salt/ssl/master/cert.pem
  ssl_version: PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
```

I added similar settings in minion. However, when I use openssl to test the port:
`openssl s_client -connect <master ip>:4505 -debug` and I get `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`. It seems the SSL is not enabled at all. How to verify if the SSL is enabled? The master and minion communication seems fine. I just to need to verify it is using SSL. I am on Centos 7 with python 2.7. Do I need to install any additional packages?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add

```
transport: tcp
```

Then you will at least get some SSL related error in `/var/log/salt/master` or `/var/log/salt/minion`

You can use `tcpdump` to capture some traffic and analyze it in wireshark to verify if the connection is ssl encrypted.

Comment: You don't have to use ssl encryption unless you want another layer of security. Communication between master and minion is already encrypted. https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/system/communication.html

Comment: The reason I was looking at SSL is for compliance. It's easier to get compliance approval if we can use standard SSL library. After some investigation, I have decided to go with a different design. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This post appeared in my searches relating to getting SaltStack to use SSL - and things have changed a bit since the original answer.

Our particular requirement wanted both server and client certificates, and the end result was as follows:

On the master you want settings like

```
ssl
  keyfile: <path to master key file>
  certfile: <path to master certificate>
  ca_certs: <path to minion CAs>
  cert_reqs: CERT_REQUIRED
  ssl_version: PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER
```

Then on the minion

```
ssl
  keyfile: <path to minion key file>
  certfile: <path to minion certificate>
  ca_certs: <path to master CAs>
  cert_reqs: CERT_REQUIRED
  ssl_version: PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT
```

The `transport = tls` option is not required - and actually prevents the `salt` command from running correctly on the master as it stops that command from connecting over the unix socket.

In our testing, we also found that the IP address which the minions use to contact the master needs to be in the master's certificate Subject Alternative Name, otherwise the minion will not verify the master's certificate.